# How to accumulate values tsql

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have to solve a problem and don't know how to do it. Im using SQL Server 2012.

I have the data like this schema:

```
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   DriverId  | BeginDate | EndDate | NextBegin | Rest in | Drive Time | Drive
             |           |         | Date      | Hours   | in Minutes | KM            
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    integer     datetime   datetime   datetime    integer    integer     decimal(10,3)

 Rest in hours = EndDate - NextBeginDate
 Drive Time in Minutes = BeginDate - EndDate
```

I have to search the first rest => 36 hours then

```
 Do
   Compute how many days are 
   SUM(DriveTime) 
   SUM(TotalKM)
 until next rest => 36 hours
 IF No More Rest EXIT DO
 Loop
```

From the begining to the first Rest is discard
From the last Rest to the end is discard

I have data in excel sheet you can download from here: [Download Excel with data example](http://www.tesma.com.ar/descargas/example.xls)

I'm sorry for my english, I hope you can understand and help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: do you have a primary key on this table?

Comment: thank you for ask, is not defined, but can have.

Comment: Based on the data in the Excel file, what do you want the result to look like?

Comment: I need a line with: DriverId, BeginDate (after the rest), EndDate (before the next rest), Days (between the rest), sum(DriverTime) (between the rest), sum(km) (between the rest). Hope I have explained well.

Comment: I have modified the excel, so you can see an example at the bottom of the sheet. Thank you again.

Comment: I still feel this is unclear. We're not searching or summing here, there's no reference point to search FROM. If, for example, there were a bunch of location markers, directional indicators, route designators, then this would be a project, but if I understand this right, each row is just a set of times in relation to rest stops already, what could possibly be needed without a reference point?

Comment: I will try to give a description, I have a lot of info that are registers from a tachograph in a vehicle. Each driver have a key with unique id. This records have a task (in this case driving) so I have a Begin and End time. Between each begin and end is the driven time for each record. Same for Kilometers begin and end, in this records this time and km are already calculated. Now, I have to make a report that ask for DateFrom to DateTo and Driver. The rest (relax, sleep?) is the time between the end of one record with the begin of another.

Comment: With this data I have to begin the search and find the first rest greater than 36 hours then begin to compute the quantity of days between this rest and the next one, sum the driving hours and km between the rest and so on until there are no more rest. The data before the first rest and after last one is discarded.

Comment: The output of this process will be inserted in a new table, so later, I can make the report. each line needs the Driver Id, The begin datetime of the first movement after the rest and the enddate time of the last movement before the next rest, quantity of days, quantity of driving hours and quantity of kilometers. This report is to control de driver job each week, the driver cant exceed the 6 days with 50 drive hours by week. Hope this help to understand. thank you for any help.

Comment: In the Excel file for the end result, why is the EndDate 2014/02/07 9:35 instead of 2014/02/07 14:31?  The sums of time and km are through 2014/02/07 14:31.

Comment: you are right, I make a misstake. I corrected the excel. thank you

Comment: Good, because it was messing up my answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several parts to the query.  The first part pulls out the rows where Rest is >= 36 and assigns a row number.  The result is stored in a CTE called BigRest.

```
with BigRest(RowNumber, DriverId, BeginDate, EndDate)
as
(
select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by d.DriverId order by d.DriverId, d.BeginDate) RowNumber,d.DriverId, d.BeginDate, d.EndDate
from Drive d 
where d.Rest >= 36
)
```

Then I assign the row number from BigRest to each row in Drive (which is what I'm calling the table that has all the data in it) based on the BeginDate.  So the data is effectively segmented by the days where Rest >= 36.  Each segment gets a number called DriveGroup.

```
;with Grouped(DriverId, BeginDate, EndDate, DriveTime, DriveKM, DriveGroup)
as
(
select d.DriverId, d.BeginDate, d.EndDate, d.Drivetime, d.DriveKM, (select Top 1 RowNumber from BigRest b where b.DriverId = d.DriverId and b.BeginDate >= d.BeginDate order by b.BeginDate)
from Drive d 
)
```

Finally, I select the data from Grouped, cross applying it with some aggregate data from itself.  We can filter out the rows where the DriveGroup is 1 or null because those represent the beginning and end rows that don't matter (the "do nothing" rows).

```
select distinct DriverId, MinBeginDate BeginDate, MaxEndDate EndDate, DATEDIFF(D, MinBeginDate, MaxEndDate)+1 Days, DriveTimeSum Drive, DriveKMSum KM
from
(
select g.DriverId, g.BeginDate, g.EndDate, g.DriveGroup, g.DriveTime, c.DriveTimeSum, c.DriveKMSum, c.MinBeginDate, c.MaxEndDate
from Grouped g
cross apply(select SUM(g2.DriveTime) DriveTimeSum, 
               SUM(g2.DriveKM) DriveKMSum, 
               MIN(g2.BeginDate) MinBeginDate, 
               MAX(g2.EndDate) MaxEndDate 
               from Grouped g2 
               where g2.DriverId = g.DriverId 
               and g2.DriveGroup = g.DriveGroup) as c
where g.DriveGroup is not null
and g.DriveGroup > 1
) x
```

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cca9c/2/0)

I'd encourage you to look at the results at each step of the query to see what's actually going on.

Comment: Jerrad, thank you. I will try this tomorow and comment.

Comment: Jerrad, thank you very much, this is exactly what I need, works like a charm. When I finish with this report I have to do another one, like this, but with some variant, is a sum by day. Thank you again.

Comment: Hi Jerrad, I post another problem like this I called this one How to accumulate values tsql, may be, you can modify this script and help me to solve it. Thank you in advance.